# How to prevent same item being added to cart?

Tags: angularjs

Im new to angular js i want to know how to prevent user from adding same item more than once to cart . i have developed a simple cart application i have attached sample screenshot below
Screen 1

[image: screen 1]

Screen 2

[image: Screen 2]

after clicking the data will be passed to an array.How can i prevent user from adding same item more than once i have used ng-repeat to retriecve data from json file.

Comment: You should use cart item `array` and check whether a cart has any pre selected product id or not. Personally I suggest to let user add product as many as they want. If your code find same product is adding again, you can increase its quantity by 1 and so on. It's for the better user experience :)

Comment: The user should have the option to add as many products of the same type as he wants. For that you could use a map that adds a pair(key, value) every time the user clicks the `Add to cart` button. Then you check for they key, and if there is not any item that equals the key value, you put the pair, else, you only increment the value for that key.

Comment: extend to @vineet -you can use in_array()

Answer (score 1):

I think you should achieve this using logic similar to below;

```
    $scope.addProduct = function(product){
    var isDuplicate = false;
    for(var i=o;i<$scope.selectedProduct.length;i++){
       if(product.id == $scope.selectedProduct[i].id){
        isDuplicate =true;
         break;
        }

   }
   if(!isDuplicate ){
        $scope.selectedProduct.push(product)


     }
 }
```